# Obtaining total number of records from .tfrecords file in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

Is it possible for obtain the total number of records from a `.tfrecords` file ? Related to this, how does one generally keep track of the number of epochs that have elapsed while training models? While it is possible for us to specify the `batch_size` and `num_of_epochs`, I am not sure if it is straightforward to obtain values such as `current epoch`, number of batches per epoch etc - just so that I could have more control of how the training is progressing. Currently, I'm just using a dirty hack to compute this as I know before hand how many records there are in my .tfrecords file and the size of my minibatches. Appreciate any help..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To count the number of records, you should be able to use [`tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard6/tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator.md).

```py
c = 0
for fn in tf_records_filenames:
  for record in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(fn):
     c += 1
```

To just keep track of the model training, [tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html) comes in handy.

Comment: Thank you ! I was wondering if there are some metadata saved in the .tfrecords file that could be used (to find the total no. of records) instead of iterating through the entire dataset using the `tf_python_io.tf_record_iterator()` function

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no metadata in the tfrecords file. There is a size at the beginning of each record (uint64 length, uint32 crc), but it's _within_ the compressed stream, so you need to uncompress everything. So there is no good way to get to this information.

Answer (score 26):

No it is not possible. [TFRecord](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/python_io#tfrecords_format_details) does not store any metadata about the data being stored inside. This file

> represents a sequence of (binary) strings. The format is not random
>   access, so it is suitable for streaming large amounts of data but not
>   suitable if fast sharding or other non-sequential access is desired.

If you want, you can store this metadata manually or use a [record_iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/python_io/tf_record_iterator) to get the number (you will need to iterate through all the records that you have:

```
sum(1 for _ in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(file_name))
```

---

If you want to know the current epoch, you can do this either from tensorboard or by printing the number from the loop.

Answer (score 12):

As [tf.io.tf_record_iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/io/tf_record_iterator?hl=th) is being deprecated, the great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44894417/6246880) of Salvador Dali should now read

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
sum(1 for _ in tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file_name))
```

Comment: This is a useful answer. Please comment on "the great answer of Salvador Dali" with a link to this answer. Also, please state in this answer in what version this can start to be used (and presumably, the other no longer works).

Answer (score 6):

As per the deprecation warning on [tf_record_iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/tf_record_iterator), we can also use eager execution to count records.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import sys

assert len(sys.argv) == 2, \
    "USAGE: {} <file_glob>".format(sys.argv[0])

tf.enable_eager_execution()

input_pattern = sys.argv[1]

# Expand glob if there is one
input_files = tf.io.gfile.glob(input_pattern)

# Create the dataset
data_set = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(input_files)

# Count the records
records_n = sum(1 for record in data_set)

print("records_n = {}".format(records_n))
```

Answer (score 1):

As tf.enable_eager_execution() is no longer valid, use:

`tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution`

`sum(1 for _ in tf.data.TFRecordDataset(FILENAMES))`