# Tensorflow Keras use tfrecords also for validation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Right now I'm using keras with tensorflow backend.
The dataset was stored in the tfrecords format. Training without any validation set is working, but how to integrate my validation-tfrecords also?

Lets assume this code as coarse skeleton:

```
def _ds_parser(proto):
    features = {
        'X': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'Y': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    }

    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(proto, features)

    # get the data back as float32
    parsed_features['X'] = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['I'], tf.float32)
    parsed_features['Y'] = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['Y'], tf.float32)

    return parsed_features['X'],  parsed_features['Y']

def datasetLoader(dataSetPath, batchSize):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(dataSetPath)

    # Maps the parser on every filepath in the array. You can set the number of parallel loaders here
    dataset = dataset.map(_ds_parser, num_parallel_calls=8)

    # This dataset will go on forever
    dataset = dataset.repeat()

    # Set the batchsize
    dataset = dataset.batch(batchSize)

    # Create an iterator
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    # Create your tf representation of the iterator
    X, Y = iterator.get_next()  

    # Bring the date back in shape
    X = tf.reshape(I, [-1, 66, 198, 3])
    Y = tf.reshape(Y,[-1,1])    

    return X, Y

X, Y = datasetLoader('PATH-TO-DATASET', 264)

model_X = keras.layers.Input(tensor=X)

model_output = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='valid', activation='relu',
                                           input_shape=(-1, 66, 198, 3))(model_X)
model_output = keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='linear')(model_output)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=model_X, outputs=model_output)

model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    target_tensors=[Y]
)

parallel_model.fit(
    epochs=epochs,
    steps_per_epoch=stepPerEpoch,
    shuffle=False,
    validation_data=????
)
```

The question is, how to pass the validation set?

I have found something related here: [gcloud-ml-engine-with-keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523822/best-way-to-process-terabytes-of-data-on-gcloud-ml-engine-with-keras), but I'm not sure how to fit this into my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the answer myself: basically it's done by simply change `import keras` to`import tensorflow.keras as keras`. Tf.keras allows you to pass the validation set also as tensor:

```
X, Y = datasetLoader('PATH-TO-DATASET', 264)
X_val, Y_val = datasetLoader('PATH-TO-VALIDATION-DATASET', 264)

# ... define and compile the model like above

parallel_model.fit(
    epochs= epochs,
    steps_per_epoch= STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
    shuffle= False,
    validation_data= (X_val, Y_val),
    validation_steps= STEPS_PER_VALIDATION_EPOCH
)
```

Comment: Hi, it currently works iwth just `import keras` also.

Answer (score 5):

First, You don't need to use iterator. Keras model will accept dataset object instead separate data/labels parameters, and will handle iteration. You only need to specify `steps_per_epoch`, hence you need to know dataset size. If you have separate tfrecords file for train/validation, then you can just create dataset object and pass it to `validation_data`. If you have one file and you'd like to split it, you can do

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('file.tfrecords')
dataset_train = dataset.take(size)
dataset_val = dataset.skip(size)
```

...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I’m using the iterator as some additional slices are performed, but not included in the above example for simplicity.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: For example Y is a matrix of size (10, 1) corresponding to 10 output labels but time shifted. The network solves a regression, the time offset is a additional parameter. Instead of regenerating the dataset, I use a simple slice to (1, 1).

Comment: I think it'd be better to update the question with the code.