# Tensorflow: Is there a way to save metadata inside a TFRecords file

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to save dataset metadata in a Tensorflow TFRecords file, at the time of file creation?

I have been looking at the new `Tensorflow Datasets` package and it is really quite nice. They have done a lot of good work to simplify the process of getting standard datasets into a tensorflow training pipeline.

One nice feature of this tool is that it saves metadata about the dataset, such as the number of examples in the dataset, or the samples in the training and test split, etc. The `DatasetInfo()` object will save the metadata for a dataset in memory. Here is an example taken from the github repo for that package:

```
    tfds.core.DatasetInfo(
        name='mnist',
        version=1.0.0,
        description='The MNIST database of handwritten digits.',
        urls=[u'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/'],
        features=FeaturesDict({
            'image': Image(shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.uint8),
            'label': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=10)
        },
        total_num_examples=70000,
        splits={
            u'test': <tfds.core.SplitInfo num_examples=10000>,
            u'train': <tfds.core.SplitInfo num_examples=60000>
        },
        supervised_keys=(u'image', u'label'),
        citation='"""
            @article{lecun2010mnist,
              title={MNIST handwritten digit database},
              author={LeCun, Yann and Cortes, Corinna and Burges, CJ},
              journal={ATT Labs [Online]. Available: http://yann. lecun. com/exdb/mnist},
              volume={2},
              year={2010}
            }
      """',
  )
```

Now if you look at this object, you can see that it contains a `FeaturesDict` and other objects that we would usually pass into a parse function when ingesting a TFRecords file into Tensorflow.

Hence I was wondering if there is a way to save this type of metadata into a TFRecords file at the time the file is encoded? Otherwise a user has to iterate through and entire dataset in order to get simple information like the number of examples. This type of information is important when calculating the number of steps to run, etc.

Comment: I believe this question can be answered by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472139/obtaining-total-number-of-records-from-tfrecords-file-in-tensorflow).

Comment: Cool. Yeah, I have seen posts on how there is no way to get the number of records in a TFRecords file without iterating over it. I was just wondering if I can save this info directly inside of a file, like something parallel to the features dictionary itself. TFRecords can get so confusing that everyone uses the same example from Google. But we should be able to write additional data to the TFRecords file--like the number of examples or training/test splits, etc? Haha, I have not found a good solution for this yet.

Comment: If I were to hack a solution, I would probably store the meta-data in a dictionary with keys as the tfrecords file names, then pickle the dictionary and load as I needed it.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at an idea like that. I thought about creating a TOML file or something at the time of TFRecords creation. Then I could just load that config when I setup the input and parse functions. It would be nice if this was all in a single file, but probably not likely. Thanks for the tips though.